# Modify default connection string for SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, openfiledialog

When I add a database to a program, Visual Studio automatically creates the following connection string:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TeamSortingTool.Properties.Settings.PlayerTeamConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PlayerTeam.sdf" providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
    <add name="PlayerTeamEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/edmPlayerTeam.csdl|res://*/edmPlayerTeam.ssdl|res://*/edmPlayerTeam.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PlayerTeam.sdf&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am trying to allow the user to select the database that they would like to open. How do I modify the connection string programmatically without losing my associated dataset and tableadapter?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use that method to call your connection string from your App.Config file to be used in the data connection or adapter

```
 public string GetConnectionStringByName()
        {
            string returnValue = null;
            ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection Name Here"];
            if (settings != null)
                returnValue = settings.ConnectionString;
            return returnValue;
        }
```

when you add a new database to your project it takes the same *connection Name* of the existing database plus a number by default.
so you can make the connection string as a variable and add the number to it when you add a new database.

**`Edit`**

By considering you will add databases to your project grammatically, then if you added a new  data base.
it will take that connection string's Name:

```
name="TeamSortingTool.Properties.Settings.PlayerTeamConnectionString1"
```

as it add a number at the end of the name of the existing database
so, you can invest the method i provided, to add the specified connection string Something  like that:

```
public string GetConnectionStringByName(int DB_Number)
        {
            string returnValue = null;
            ConnectionStringSettings settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection Name Here"];
            if (settings != null)
                returnValue = settings.ConnectionString+Convert.ToString(DB_Number);
            return returnValue;
        }
```

as the `DB_Number` variable could be saved in an `XML` file in order not to be loosed and its increased each time you add  database.

So, if you add a new database to the existing 1 the connection Name should be:

```
name="TeamSortingTool.Properties.Settings.PlayerTeamConnectionString1"
```

and if you added another database the `DB_Number` will be increased by 1 to change the connection name to be :

```
name="TeamSortingTool.Properties.Settings.PlayerTeamConnectionString2"
```

and enable the user to choose with connection string he wants to use.

on the other hand . if your databases added manually before the application runs.
it will be easier to Handle as what you just have to do is to save your connection string in a data structure as an array and call the wanted connection to use

that is what i figured out from your question

Comment: When I try to use this piece of code, it gives me the error **The type or namespace name 'ConnectionStringSettings' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)?**. Also, it gives me the error **The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context**. I tried **using System.Configuration** however, this did not fix this issue. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. I had to add **System.Configuration** to my references.

Comment: I solved the errors with the code, however I'm not sure how this helps me modify the ConnectionString to point it to the database I want to open or the new one I create (I'm copying the template DB to a new file).